# Centering 3D FFT

Tags: 3d, fft, fftw

again I have a question concerning centering a FFT result. In this case in 3D space with FFTW Library. At the moment I have implemented the concept shown in the picture below. It shows the subdivided frequency space. Each sub cube (1-8) represents an eighth of the complete space. The aim is to relocate the low frequencies at the center of this 2x2x2 cube where all eight sub-cubes meet. After this relocation step I simply shift the origin to the center of the cube.

[image: Centering 3D Space FFT result]

Currently it is done directly after the forward fft und directly before the ifft but I am not sure if this method is correct since I am getting strange results when I apply a filter. Without filtering  I get `OUTPUT = INPUT` as expected.

After some hours of searching I could not find any example that centers the fft result. The corresponding 2D method seems to work. Is there a common way to deal with it, since for low pass filtering I need the low frequencies in the center and the high at the edges (which is not given by fftw by default).

Greetings

Wolf

Answer (score 1):

This is covered in the FFTW FAQ, see http://www.fftw.org/faq/section3.html#centerorigin. What you need to do is multiply every element by: (-1)^(i+j+k) where i, j and k are element indices.